# Как можно получить имя файла из uri, где данными является octet-stream, а не ссылка на файл в памяти

Tags: java, android, path, uri, whatsapp

Имеется uri вида: content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/66381

mime-type: application/octet-stream

Судя по [другим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465601/get-path-from-another-app-whatsapp) ответам на StackOverflow получить ссылку на файл в ФС невозможно, как это описано, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985286/convert-content-uri-to-actual-path-in-android-4-4/27271131).

Как я понял, WhatsApp передаёт стрим, который необходимо переделывать в InputStream и дальше делать уже всё необходимое.

Так вот, откуда в этом случае можно извлечь имя файла? При шаринге, например, в Телеграм, он определяет имя файла нормально и отправляет его, значит, это возможно

Comment: Пробовали такое решение https://stackoverflow.com/q/5568874/4398606 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы все верно понимаете, не все что доступно по URI, является объектом файловой системы.

В вашем случае имя ресурса можно попытаться вытянуть таким образом:

```
Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) { // if null, uri cannot be resolved
    int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String fileName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
    cursor.close();
}
```

Естественно, ни о каком расширении речи быть не может.
Тут может помочь `MIME type`:

```
mimeType = ctx.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri);
```